# Magento Connect 2.0 - Connection Error try again later

Tags: magento

Is anyone else having problems installing new addons using the new Magento Connect version (2.0)? I just installed the latest version, went to install my language packs using the new url’s and i get "Connection Error try again later.” I tried all yesterday and today and still get the same problem. This is an example addon:

http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Locale_Mage_Core_fr_FR

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, on investigation I found that PHP-XML was not installed on the server.

As I was on Amazon Ubuntu, so following steps resolved the problem:

1. yum install php-xml
2. restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Found at http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tips/magento-connect-v2-0-connection-error-try-again-later.php

When installing an extension from Magento Connect with the URL http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/example/EXAMPLE if you are finding that the error persists one small thing you can try is to remove the http:// from the beginning of the url.